# does a consistent closed theory in a finite languge, which is not finitely axiomatizable has an infinite model?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

does a consistent closed theory in a finite languge, which is not finitely axiomatizable has an infinite model?
i need help to know if this is true or not.
and also if it is true can i prove it by compactness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*: Use compactness to prove that if a theory has arbitrarily large finite models, then it has an infinite model. Now observe that for every finite $n$, there are finitely many structures of size $n$ up to isomorphism (since the language is finite).